# Integration from a set of acceleration data to position

Tags: python, scipy, physics, numerical-integration

I'm trying for a project to integrate acceleration data in order to have an approximation of the position. I used a real simple set of data to start with, with a constant acceleration.

```py
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

t = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7]
a = [-9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8]
v = cumtrapz(a, t, initial=0)
z = cumtrapz(v, t, initial=5)
```

The result is quite satisfying, apart from the fact that the initial condition for the position is only respected for the first value, and I don't understand how I can change this ?
[image]

Comment: I've edited your tags. Be careful when choosing your tags since [tag:integration] is not for mathematical integration (if you go to the tag it says you should use [tag:numerical-integration] for those questions). You should always read the tag description when using a new tag to make sure it's actually what you think it is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` is left for backward compatibility, you should use the newer [`scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html#scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid) function. Secondly, if you read the documentation you'll see that `initial` is not an initial condition but simply a value prepended onto the array, which would normally be one element shorter than the original data.

> initial : scalar, optional
>
> If given, insert this value at the beginning of the returned result. 0 or None are the only values accepted. Default is None, which means res has one element less than y along the axis of integration.

There is also a deprecation warning that, starting version 1.12.0, providing anything but 0 or `None` will result in a warning

This shows the sizes of the result:

```py
from scipy.integrate import cumulative_trapezoid

t = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7]
a = [-9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8, -9.8]
print(len(t), len(cumulative_trapezoid(a, t)), len(cumulative_trapezoid(a, t, initial=0)))  # 15, 14, 15
```

To enforce your initial condition, you should set `initial=0` and then add the initial condition to the result.

```py
v0 = 0.
z0 = 5.
v = cumulative_trapezoid(a, t, initial=0) + v0
z = cumulative_trapezoid(v, t, initial=0) + z0
```

[image]